# retina image on a 3gs or 3g phone

Tags: iphone, uiimage, retina-display, iphone-3gs

I have a kind of problem where there are two set of photos in my photo viewer. One is a retina image and another is a image with less resolution. the size of the placeholder is around 300X200. The no retina based image is exactly the same size 300X200 and retina images is almost double the size. My question is what problem will we face when a high resolution image is placed in a non retina image, i know the image will get displayed for sure, but i want to know what could be other hidden issues.

can someone surely say that a high resolution image in the placeholder is not going to create any image that will be fine. i know my question looks real silly, but want to clear that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is only one problem, memory.

Since the 3G and 3GS have less ram then 4/4S you will run out of memory faster.

Answer (score 0):

One more problem may arise,
It is the frame size of your UIImageView. If you are creating the frame dynamically (based on image size), it will create bigger frame (which is not accepted). However if you are creating the frame with hard code values, its fine.